# Can tanh be used as an output for a binary classifier?

Tags: python, classification, keras, tensorflow

I am creating a binary classifier in Keras and here;s the code

```py
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=60, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I was wondering, if the dataset's range is changed from [0,1] to [-1,1], shouldn't I be able to use tanh as the activation of the output layer? If so, what are the advantages of one activation over the other?

Answer (score 3):

If you label your data using `-1` and `1` as classes, then yes you can. However, there are two reasons why data scientists normally prefer Sigmoid activations:

- Loss functions, such as cross entropy based, are designed for data in the `[0, 1]` interval.
- Better interpretability: data in `[0, 1]` can be thought as probabilities of belonging to acertain class, or as a model's confidence about it.

But yeah, you can use Tanh and train useful models with it.

Answer (score 0):

For a binary classifier, it is prominent to use sigmoid as the activation function. The sigmoid function's range is $[ 0 , 1 ]$. That makes sense since we need a probability which could determine two ( binary ) classes i.e 0 and 1.

If you are using tanh ( hyperbolic tangent ) it will produce an output which ranges from -1 to 1. In this case, we cannot determine the binary classes.

**Hence, we require sigmoid rather than tanh especially for binary classification.**

Comment: Worth adding that the OP's chosen loss function `binary_croseentroyp`, also will not function correctly for input range $[-1,1]$

Answer (score 0):

A problem where you classify an example as belonging to one of two classes.

The problem is framed as predicting the likelihood of an example belonging to class one, e.g. the class that you assign the integer value 1, whereas the other class is assigned the value 0.

Output Layer Configuration: One node with a sigmoid activation unit.
Loss Function: Binary-Cross-Entropy, also referred to as Logarithmic loss.
Another point to note is softmax is a generalization of sigmoid for producing probabilities for multi-class problems so that the probabilities strictly sum to 0,hence rather than using tanh go for sigmoid or either softmax(it is same as sigmoid for binary classification problems).